# table rates for italy / rest of the world

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I need a little help.

I ve to set shipping rates for a magento store:

- 10€ for Italy
- 20€ for the rest of the world

Simple as that, no matter on weight or other shipping parameters. Anyone can help me?..I think I ve to set up a simple CSV file..

Thanks in advance

M :)

Answer (score 0):

System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Table rate Shippng Methods > YES

Change Current Configuration scope to "Main Website" .

Export csv = > download the csv file, than fill the excel sheet .

Enter country codes and give * in other fields, at the last column enter shipping charges.

and import it again to Backend.

source : http://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/